# PHP Unit testing fails to pass all test

Tags: php, phpunit

I am creating a class with some unit tests, but i am not able to pass few tests. Example is shown below.

#### Unit Test

```
class OffsetTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{


   /**
    * @dataProvider getIllegalOffsets
    * @expectedException \InvalidArgumentException
    * @param $offset
    */
   public function testIllegalParameters($offset)
    {
        new \OffsetEncodingAlgorithm($offset);

        $this->fail('Exception should be thrown');
    }
    /**
     * Data provider for {@link OffsetTest::testIllegalParameters()}
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIllegalOffsets()
    {
        return [
            [-1],
        ];
    }
}
```

#### My Class

```
<?php

class Offset
{
    public function __construct(int $offset = 13)
    {
       try {
            if ($offset < 0) {
                throw new Exception('Exception should be thrown');
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
        $this->offset = $offset;
    }
}
```

This how the test progress go
[image]

I want all to be passed

Comment: How do you run the test? and also, do you meant to use `@dataProvider`?

Comment: I run it via `composer test` `getIllegalOffsets()` provides the feed `-1` for the test

Comment: I think you might want to try adding `$this->expectException()` inside `testIllegalParameters()`

Comment: I can't change the tests, its provided to be like that

Comment: Your code example contains one test case. But in screenshot there is lot of them. Test failures might not caused by this test.

Comment: @AlexanderYancharuk all failing tests are related to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While testing for the `testIllegalParameters()` which expects an exception in return, you don't have to use `try-catch` block. Just throw an exception in an `if` condition simply.

Secondly throw a correct type of exception that is defined in the test case `InvalidArgumentException`

```
class Offset
{
    public function __construct(int $offset = 13)
    {
        if ($offset < 0) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Offset should be greater than equal to zero');
        } else {
            $this->offset = $offset;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can understand it